# Error Installing ETH Brownie

Tags: web3.py, brownie, error, vyper, pipx

So I get a error for each of the 3 different processes when I attempt to install eth-brownie on my Mac OS...

1. With "pip install eth-brownie", I get the error

```
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> typed-ast

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

2. When I put "pipx install eth-brownie", I get

```
Fatal error from pip prevented installation.

pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    yarl

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:209:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
    yarl/_quoting_c.c:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

3. Why I attempt "pipx install git+https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git@master", I run into:

```
Fatal error from pip prevented installation.

pip seemed to fail to build package:
    vvm==0.1.0

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.3.0 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 0.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 0.3.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 0.3.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 0.3.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 0.3.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 0.3.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 0.3.7 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 3.0.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.11; 3.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.11
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vyper==0.3.7 (from eth-brownie) (from versions: 0.1.0b1, 0.1.0b2, 0.1.0b3, 0.1.0b4, 0.1.0b5, 0.1.0b6, 0.1.0b7, 0.1.0b8, 0.1.0b9, 0.1.0b10, 0.1.0b11, 0.1.0b12, 0.1.0b13, 0.1.0b14, 0.1.0b15, 0.1.0b16, 0.1.0b17, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11, 0.2.12, 0.2.13, 0.2.14, 0.2.15, 0.2.16)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for vyper==0.3.7

Error installing eth-brownie from spec 'git+https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git@master'.
```

and as a bonus
just to check I run "brownie"
and get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/brownie", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('eth-brownie==1.19.2', 'console_scripts', 'brownie')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/brownie", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 198, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.19.2-py3.11.egg/brownie/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.19.2-py3.11.egg/brownie/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_brownie-1.19.2-py3.11.egg/brownie/project/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I am not sure what to do and would appreciate the help because I am looking to develop using vyper and from my knowledge brownie is the only application rn thats supportive of python really.

I am open to tips, suggestions, and constructive criticism

Comment: Looks like pipx is the preferred install method.  Did you do all the pipx install steps exactly? 1) python3 -m pip install --user pipx
2) python3 -m pipx ensurepath, and 3) Restart your terminal after installing pipx.  Based on your brownie error message, it looks like some part of your installed tools/packages is out-of-date and causing an old version of brownie to install.  By the way, are you using homebrew for any of these tools?  I installed brownie a few months ago on mac.  I use brew.  If I run into trouble, I sometimes uninstall and reinstall prerequisites

Comment: Other things to try: I see you're using Python 3.11.  Maybe Brownie isn't ready for 3.11?  Consider reverting to a Python 3.10 (that's what I use).  Are you using a virtual environment?  If not, consider using venv to isolate your Brownie install from other Python stuff you've got.  I'm no Python expert.  Maybe a more knowledgable Python person will add some diagnostic advice.  If all else fails you could install Brownie on a Docker image.  That would let you move ahead with Brownie while you investigate why the install doesn't work on your macos.

Comment: Also (just remembered), I followed the Curve tutorial on installing Brownie too.  It's a Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo6YRNf3eZM .

Answer (score 1):

From experience, it's much easier to use brownie with Python's virtual env (venv):

```
pip install virtualenv    
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

You can then log into it :

```
source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate
```

And install `eth-brownie`:

```
pip install eth-brownie
```